# How to manually give Google Popular Times data?

Tags: google-maps

I frequently consult Google Popular Times when going to coffee shops for a very short time. It doesn't pay off to wait for 10 minutes, if you just have a ten minute break. Last week, while I was considering going to the coffee shop X, I consulted Google Popular Times. It was wrong (for that day) and beside the indication I noticed a question something "Correct? Tell us!". This I could click and choose "Less busy, More busy, accurate". Today this button does not appear.

How can I make this button appear? And, once appeared, should I feed it the current state or the usual state?

I speculate it may depend on whether Google does or does not perceive me as close by, based on ip. This may not be the case in some wifis, which make you appear as a British.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? How may I improve?